Changing the charset for double click highlight in Mousepad editor
Can I modify the character set which is used to recognize a single word for the double click word highlight in  Mousepad, the default text editor in Debian xfce4?
Eg. I would like to highlight words separated by m letter and the space. Then in the word memory two words would be highligted e and ory. When one double-clicks on e, e will be highlighted, and when one double-clicks ory, ory will be higligted.
I mean a way to change the charset that defines separators when one double-clicks words in the editor.

So how would you want to modify it? What should be selected? What should not be selected? What if a path has spaces? What characters do you want to be used and how? Are a|b, a b, a?b, a%b etc. one "word"?  Please [edit] and clarify.

@terdon Let's say the only separators are the space and EOL. Then I gonna think about it.

OK, please EDIT the question and describe the specifications for what you are asking. I don't use mousepad and I have no idea if modifying this is possible or even if it is something that can be modified for a specific tool or if it is handled by something at the OS level. However, in order for anyone who does know these things to be able to answer, they will need clear and precise specifications of what behavior you want to see, so please edit the question and add your specs.

@terdon thank you I improved the question.
